# Using several sources layers from the same tileset in Mapbox

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a tileset where I am adding several layers, I want to call them so i can organize the order I receive it. I want first to show source layer1 and then underlaying source layer2. I have tried also generating one tileset with one field but the display in the sites doesn't correspond with the order I have stablished in the JSON when generating the mbtiles.

```
'tileset-id': {
    type: 'vector',
    url: 'mapbox://mapboxurl.tileset'

'tileset-id': [
    {
      id: 'tileset-id-layer',
      'source-layer': 'source layer1',
      source: 'tileset-id-source',
      minzoom: 13,
      type: 'fill',
      paint: {
        'fill-color': '#2BBAAB',
        'fill-outline-color': '#FFFFFF',
        'fill-opacity': 0.4
      }
    },
    {
      id: 'tileset-id-layer',
      'source-layer': 'source layer2',
      source: 'tileset-id-source',
      minzoom: 13,
      type: 'fill',
      paint: {
        'fill-color': '#2BBAAB',
        'fill-outline-color': '#FFFFFF',
        'fill-opacity': 0.4
      },
      filter: ['in', 'field', '']
    }
  ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello after surfing I found these [details in mapbox](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#layout-fill-fill-sort-key) which do the workaround sorting the layers based in a order preestablished.

so adding this line to the object make it work

```
layout: {
        'fill-sort-key': ['-', ['get', 'field_order']]
      },
```